# Re-importing blank (NULL) fields doesn't seem to work Dynamics CRM 2016 (on-premise)

Tags: import, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a bunch of dates I need to blank out for certain records. I did an Advanced Find to get the records. Exported them, blanked out the date fields and reimported. The only change made was to blank out the fields and the import came up as a partial failure for all records and the date fields in question were all left intact.

Anyone know if there is a "PROPER" way to export/re-import a blank field that used to have data in it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have CRM 2016 on-premise, but I remember something similar steps like this. I tested this successfully in CRM Online D365 V9.

1. Export the data from view/Advanced find (will be identical)
2. Use "Dynamic worksheet" option, open the file & wipe out the date field data (after "Enable content" and "Enable Editing" in Excel), then save it
3. Import the same file using "Import data" option

[image]

You can try to to Bulk Edit also. Choose all the records, then click "Edit" button in ribbon to open up the Bulk edit form & do bulk changes.

Comment: The steps suggested are exactly the steps I did, which didn't remove the dates. The first thing I thought of was bulk edit, but you can't just "blank out" a field in the bulk edit, you can only put something in a field to add that change into all records.